# Why cannot we use thick wire in alternating current production?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors

Why cannot we use thick wire in alternating current even though thick wires have got low resistance as $R$ is *inversely proportional to area of cross section*?

Comment: 1. Don't use all caps, that comes across as unfriendly shouting. 2. Who says "we" can't use thick wires for alternating currents? However, googling "thick wire alternating current" directly leads to the [Skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), at least for me, which would indicate that using thicker wires would be kind of a waste. Can you elaborate what exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 4):

[The skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), whereby a sinusoidally-varying-with-time field only penetrates to a depth inversely proportionalal to frequency, is the reason we cannot naïvely use thick conductors. We could have a thick, cylindrical conductor, but if its radius is much more than the skin depth, then most of the conductor's cross-section won't be used and will not lead to a lower resistance.

However, it's not altogether true that we can't use thick conductors: we can use thick total cross sections, as long as those cross-sections are designed with the skin effect in mind. For example, hollow cylindrical conductors of a large radius can have high cross sectional conducting areas even if the thickness is of the order of the skin depth. In power transmission, one uses thick wires comprising layers of strength-giving, but poorly conducting, steel alternating with layers of highly conducting aluminum strands, whose radius is chosen to be less than the skin depth. The whole structure has a great deal of conducting area, which is used effectively through clever design.